# Sitemap in different domain and robots.txt crawling

Tags: google-search, sitemap, robots.txt

I have the following subdomains:

- `www.example.com`
- `api.example.com`

The subdomain `api.example.com` is supposed to be invisible to Google. Its `robots.txt` had a `Disallow /` directive. But I don't want any server processing at all to go on at `www.example.com`.

The main site`www.example.com/robots.txt` points to `api.example.com/sitemap.xml` (sitemap requires processing).

The problem is that Google's Search Console is complaining that the `sitemap.xml` is blocked by the `robots.txt` file... I presume it's reading the robots on `api.domain.com`. So I tried pointing www's robots to `www.domain.com/sitemap.xml` and putting a redirect there. No luck.

So it seems I'm forced to put an `Allow /sitemap.xml` on api's `robots.txt`. Will Google get confused by this? Will it try to index the sitemap's urls (the sitemap is 100% absolute urls pointing to `www.example.com`) and somehow dilute authority between the two domains? `api.example.com` is not registered on Search Console as a property.

Comment: Just for clarification, are example.com and domain.com different here?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should register api.domain.com in Google Search Console (GSC).
This will allow you to see how many pages from that sub-domain is getting indexed by Google.

You can also use GSC to block api.domain.com completely from Google if you want. (depending on the situation this is not recommended)

If you don't want api.domain.com to get indexed, it should not have a sitemap to start with.
Also, you should not include any of api.domain.com in the www. version's sitemap.

In other words, Google will get confused because you are telling Google to don't access the api. site, yet providing a Sitemap which is supposed to help Google to index the site.